# defining array size in custom message using constant

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to define the size of an array in a message definition using a constant like this:

```
int32 NUM_NODES = 128

int32[NUM_NODES]  nodes
```

This doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
  [  5%] Generating ../msg_gen/lisp/RAW_CONFIG.lisp, ../msg_gen/lisp/_package.lisp, ../msg_gen/lisp/_package_RAW_CONFIG.lisp
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 871, in <module>
      generate_msg(sys.argv[1])
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_lisp.py", line 725, in generate_msg
      (_, spec) = roslib.msgs.load_from_file(msg_path, package)
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/msgs.py", line 669, in load_from_file
      raise MsgSpecException('%s: %s'%(file_name, e))
  roslib.msgs.MsgSpecException: RAW_CONFIG.msg: int32[NUM_NODES] is not a legal message type
```

Is there a workaround?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50293/defining-array-size-in-custom-message-using-constant/) by [emdr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3773/emdr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message generators do not support this feature. You cannot define the array size using a constant.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1